# Remove RSS Feed icon(link) from Joomla K2

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-k2

Somebody can help me with this problem
i have tried already everything (i think)
i want to remove rss feed icon from category in joomla3 k2

thanks

Comment: Go to k2 category template php file and remove (or) comment feed icon block there.

Comment: It's very simple, you just have multiple categories with the RSS feed icon set - a feed of articles from multiple categories will show the icon even if it is just set for one category, so disable it for each category - even if those categories are set to inherit properties from a main category (where you have since disabled the feed link) the icon will still show so you'll need to change each one independently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the category that you are displaying, and under Category view options, there is an option to Show or Hide the RSS feed icon.

[image]

Comment: While that should do it, you may need to follow Andrew's suggestion and create/edit a K2 sub-template.

Answer (score 0):

> Simply do this....
>
> ```
> Menu Manager: Edit Menu Item (Blog Menu) -> Basic Options -> 
> Disable RSS feed (head) link and Disable RSS feed icon
> ```

Answer (score 0):

From the top navigation bar of Joomla backend, you may follow the steps below:

```
Content > [Article Manager] > [Options] (Upper-Right Corner) > [Integration] (tab) > set [Show Feed Link] to [Hide].
```

I hope this will help you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Open up the K2 component screen. Select the parameters button (top-right of screen). Select Layout & Views then scroll down and select Hide for the rss feed

Hope this helps.